# Seria protocol issue comestero rm5

Tags: arduino, ascii, protocols

I have a comestero rm5 evolution coin validator and i try to read the output serial values on a serial monitor like putty or realterm and i get nothing. The cable works for sure as it connects with the program given by comestero.

The serial protocol says that i have to send 00 command then wait for answer then send 1D and then when i drop a coin i will get a value on my serial monitor..the thing is i have tried many combinations and still nothing..i want to use it on an arduino project

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct baudrate?

Comment: Yes it's 96008N1 as stated in the manual